# Best Pattern/ Model for Converting JSON data to RDMS (Zendesk specifically)

Tags: sql, json, transformation, etl, zendesk

I'm trying to gather data from Zendesk's Incremental Ticket Events API (in JSON) into relational MySQL database -- why?

Well, actually, the end goal is I want a metric (count the number of ticket solves per day) -- automatically imported into a master database. So the SQL may be unnecessary, but I'm not sure the best way to count the number of solves by parsing JSON. I cannot make an API call to Zendesk's calculated metrics directly.

So basically, the recurring JSON structure is as follows (within a master label called "ticket_events"):

```
 { 
"child_events":[
{"id": 6563223, "via": "Mail", "via_reference_id":null, >random field name1<:result},
{"id": 2321513, "via": "Mail", "via_reference_id":null, >random field name2<:result},
{.... for 1-n elements} ]

"id":8784848451,
"ticket_id":16037,
"updater_id":54548184848,
"timestamp":1416812299
}
```

When I put >random field name1< this refers to the ticket field that was updated - so it could be named anything. Priority, sender, receiver, status, etc.

I'm only interested in the **status** field within >random field name<. Specifically, I just want to locate **"status":"solved"** -- that means the status was updated to solved. Each time this happens, I want to pull the timestamp, ticket_id, and updater_id, which are all siblings to "child events".

So here's the issue. Obviously SQL databases require a fixed number of fields. So I can't pull all the child events. Not a problem, I just need one child event (status). Well, even if I were to find the correct JSON query expression in my tool (Pentaho) to only pull $child_events.status elements, well --- not every update has a status update. And the tool wants a 1:1 ratio between all fields.

Actually --- I guess I can put the giant "child events" array into one large SQL field ... and simply do a parse (in_str) or something in the SQL environment for "status_solved" ... I don't know. I'm a bit out of my depth here -- how would you best parse what I'm trying to accomplish into a SQL database? Or is there a better approach altogether that involves skipping SQL?

Again, I'm using Pentaho, which allows java and javascript transformations of the data before I even begin parsing it as JSON if need be.

Again, I'd like status: solve events, timestamp, updater_id, ticket_id. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think javascript is the best tool here. pseudocode:

```
var all_children = eval(json_text);
var found = [];
for each object_with_child_events
    for each child_events item
        if (item.status !== 'undefined')
           if (item.status == 'solved')
              found.append(object.{events, timestamp, updater_id, ticket_id});
              break;
```